# Java Netbeans: How to open the JPanel from another class?

Tags: java, swing

I have a main.java file which I like to use to call the GUI made in JPanel.
It's my first NetBeans experience though, so be gentle :-) ...

It fails to compile; the error i get is :`Erroneous sym type: main.GUI.GUI` (which makes sense as it is interpreted).

But now: HOW DO I FIX IT??

I've tried `GUI.GUI();` as well, but without positive results..
(I'm used to programming C++, but since import is not a true option in java (or is it?).

My main.java:

```
package main;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GUI obj = new GUI();
        obj.GUI();
    }  
}
```

My  GUI.java file:

```
package main;

public class GUI extends javax.swing.JPanel {
    public GUI() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
    }                                
}
```

Comment: for which line does the error occur?

Comment: the part that wants to call obj.GUI();

Comment: I don't know all your code, but remove `obj.GUI();`. You are trying to call the constructor again, which makes no sense. The object is already created after `GUI obj = new GUI();`,  the constructor has been called already

Comment: I totally agree, I removed it, but now I still do not see the JPanel, while it should..

Comment: Hint for future question: If someone asks a question, modify your question instead of answering in the comments, in order to keep the comment section clean and the question better.

Comment: There might be several problems: add the Panel to a JFrame, set the visibility, ...

Comment: You sir, are correct, just found out myself, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to display the GUI from your Main class. One thing to keep in mind is that a JPanel itself cannot be displayed. It must be added to a JFrame before it shows. Try something like:

```
package main;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GUI obj = new GUI(); // creates your panel
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("some title"); // creates the frame
        frame.add(obj);
        frame.setSize(200,300);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

GUI obj = new GUI();
it created new object of GUI. So, the constructor is operated already. The constructor method is special method, that plays when new object is created from the class.

Comment: No -- the constructor is most definitely *not* a method. Please correct your answer so as not to mislead newbies.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, and I said it's "special method" not an ordinary method. It's for  simplifying the image for newbies.

Comment: Not your down-voter by the way, but I think that even calling it a special method is misleading. For one, it cannot be inherited like a method can.

Comment: Would you read these article (just the few first lines) about the definition of the constructor, here "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_(object-oriented_programming)" and here "http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/constructors.html"